# Too many pages causes Wordpress admin to be unusable

Tags: wordpress

We have a WordPress website that now has around 9k pages in it after an import of many location targeted pages. The frontend runs perfectly fine and there is no performance damage (after I replaced wp_list_pages with a custom MySQL query), but the Page administration section can't even be touched. All other sections of the admin open fine. Even if I navigate to a page on the frontend and use the Edit Page link, it's never able to pull up the Edit Page screen. Changing permalink structure doesn't help, which I know that was an issue with pre 3.0 WordPress. Also tried disabling all plugins and running w3cache, no help there. I'm running on WordPress 3.3.2.

My only alternative I'm thinking would be to split the website up into smaller subsites built on a Wordpress Network, but that would cause at least a month of delay of restructuring the entire website.

**EDIT**
A wordpress developer mentioned that I could "turn off hierarchical display in edit.php. A
filter in wp_edit_posts_query() might be able to accommodate this" as a potential workaround. Does any one have experience in dealing with something like that?

Comment: You might want to try this on http://wordpress.stackexchange.com. 9k pages doesn't seem like that many. This should be workable.

Comment: Thanks! I'll get people's thoughts there too.

Comment: Nothing seems to be working, even tried out 2 different hosts  :(   it looks like I'm going to have to attempt splitting the site into multiple Wordpress Network sites. This seems so silly that Wordpress has such an inefficient query to pull up a page edit screen that literally breaks the admin.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is not with WordPress; it's perfectly scalable. The problem is with your server and what you're doing with plugins.

W3TC won't help with admin. Deactivate W3TC cache, too; it can conflict with APC php configs and database caching on the server. Try [WP Super Cache](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/wp-super-cache/) and php (not mod_rewrite) caching.

What you need to do is work with your MySQL server and run https://github.com/rackerhacker/MySQLTuner-perl to optimize my.cnf and MySQL. Admin is running lots of queries against the DB to build that list of pages in admin, and MySQL needs help in allocating memory and caching queries.

If you don't have access to your MySQL server and my.cf, time to get a VPS or dedicated server. You can't run that large of a WP site on a cheap shared host.

**Also raise your PHP memory allocation** in php.ini to 128M you have it to spare. Or in wp-config.php, try

`define('WP_MEMORY_LIMIT', '128M');`

right after the opening `<?php` and below the cache call inserted by W3TC.

Comment: Thanks, I'll give those items a shot. So you think this is doable then? Also, not sure if it matters or not on the memory timeout, but it never actually gets to a timeout message, just sits and spins.

Comment: php timeout and php memory are two different settings in php.ini. More memory will help WP run faster.

Comment: Yeah, upgrading the memory limit to 256M in both wordpress and PHP settings still didn't seem to be enough. I'll have to keep trying other things out.

Comment: You have a database bottleneck. Use mysqltuner. Deactivate W3TC cache, too; it can conflict with APC php configs and database caching on the server.

Comment: Thanks. You'll have to excuse my ignorance, but how do I run that pearl script? Via SSH? Is there a specific directory I need to run it from? I'm a little inexperienced with web server management.

Comment: Those are really completely different questions. Yes, you use SSH, wget and perl (not pearl). Search on those terms for usage. If you're going to run your own box, you need to learn server admin. The problem is not with WordPress; it's perfectly scalable. The problem is with your server and what you're doing with plugins.

Comment: Are you kidding me? Does Wordpress really need to run umpteen thousand queries for one page load!!! Just make your database better. What the hell!?!?!